# spring batch initialise schema option in application.ymal not working with spring boot 3

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a spring batch application with spring boot. In Applicaton.yml I have the option to initialize schema set to always
spring:
batch:
jdbc:
initialize-schema: always

This option was working fine until the application was powered by spring boot 2.4  but upon switching to spring boot 3.0.4 this option has no effect but also no exception is thrown .

The thing is that the rest of the operation of spring batch is working as per normal that is to say that I have a DataSource Bean and Transaction Manager configured in my application and once I create the batch schema tables manually the rest of the application works fine.

The DB server I using is POSTGRESQL.

Just wanted to know if anyone has an idea about the issue could be and also the possible fix for the same
Thanks and Regards
Jaswinder Sodhi

with spring batch tried
spring:
batch:
jdbc:
initialize-schema: always
the expectation was that this would automatically initialise the spring batch schema for POSTGRES which is the configured Datasource in the application also have a bean defining that datasource
but the schema is not getting initialised  after upgrading to spring boot 3 (with spring boot 2 was working fine )